Do we need MPPT in grid synchronization and string inverters?
I have two questions regarding the MPPT grid synchronization. I have seen that it takes a few minutes for the inverter to get synchronized with the grid. I want to ask that does the inverter first generate a wave of 230VAC from the solar panels and then connect it to the grid?? Also during this wave generation is it necessary to use MPPT or a normal PWM mode is used since I am not drawing much power beacuse grid is disconnected. After it is connected to the sink (grid) I used an MPPT mode to transmit maximum power keeping voltage in a certain limits.
Secondly in case I am using the inverter like a string inverter where the DC energy is converter into AC directly. In this case do I need an MPPT or I can use a simple PWM to maintain a constant rms of 220VAC. Since my load is restricted (limited home appliances) and not a big sink MPPT may tend towards a higher voltage on a bright sunny day when production is high to keep maximum power.
So shall I use PWM mode or I use MPPT in this case also restricting it in a certain limits of voltage.
Kindly help me clear these two confusions regarding inverters and their control.

becasuse an mppt may give greater fluctions in voltage to  find mpp. Also the maximum power point voltage may be higher or lower than the required voltage range.

You only use MPPT when you have a load (like a battery charger or water heater, or the electric grid itself) that can accept a variable amount of power, so you optimize the conversion for the maximum power that the solar panels can deliver. Otherwise, you're only drawing the amount of power that the load requires, and MPPT is pointless.

As stated by Dave Tweed we use an MPPT only when we have a large sink that can consume a huge amount of current. At times of synchronizing and load providing in string inverter the load is limited and can consume limited current so at that stage we donot need to use an MPPT and a normal PWM constant voltage mechanism will work.
